# I want know that all up and down spin of particles have same angular momentum

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, quantum-spin

Do all free electrons have the same angular momentum?

Answer (score 1):

All electrons are not just identical, they are indistinguishable by nature, so whatever goes for one goes for all. And any electron has an intrinsic angular momentum of:

$$ ||J|| = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\hbar$$

This holds for all spin $1/2$ fermions: mu, tau, the neutrinos, and the quarks, and even composite states that are in pure spin $1/2$ eigenstates (such as protons, neutrons, lambdas....).

And of course, their antimatter counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jeb's answer, for intrinsic angular momentum, i.e. spin, free electrons can have angular momentum with respect to any point  in space.

In three dimensions, [the angular momentum](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/amom.html) for a point particle is  $r × p$, the cross product of the particle's position vector $r$ (relative to some origin) and its momentum vector $p = mv$ .

This angular momentum, in contrast to spin angular momentum,  will depend on the point chosen in the study and on the momentum of each electron, so in this case different momenta electrons will have different angular momenta  to the same space point. Thus when spin is added vectorially to the angular momentum , free electrons will differ between themselves  for total angular momentum to the same point.